# How to compare "peewee.DateField" with "datatime.date"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, peewee, datefield

I wrote the below program to fetch some rows of my database that contain information about the users whom born after `22-Jan-1963`:

```
import datetime as dt
import peewee as pw
db = pw.SqliteDatabase('people.db')

class Person(pw.Model):
    name = pw.CharField()
    birthday = pw.DateField(formats=['%d-%b-%Y'])

    class Meta:
        database = db # This model uses the "people.db" database.

db.create_tables([Person])

bob = Person(name = 'Bob', birthday = '21-Jan-1960')
james = Person(name = 'James', birthday = '22-Jan-1965')
steve = Person(name = 'Steve', birthday = '20-Jan-1970')
alex = Person(name = 'Alex', birthday = '18-Jan-1975')
bob.save()
james.save()
steve.save()
alex.save()

for item in Person.select().where(Person.birthday > dt.date(1963,1,22)):
    print item.name,item.birthday, item.birthday > dt.date(1963,1,22)
```

But when I run this, output is not what I have expected (I expect *James, Steve and Alex* in the output):

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Bob 1960-01-21 False
James 1965-01-22 True
Steve 1970-01-20 True
>>>
```

Well, I replaced `dt.date(1963,1,22)` with `"22-Jan-1963"` in the `where()` method, and now the result is:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
James 1965-01-22 True
>>>
```

As you see above, it is not correct still.

What shall I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I absolutely do not know PeeWee, but given that Sqlite does not have a native date-time format (it mimics it as a string), you may want to try and change the date format to `"%Y-%m-%d"`; this will automatically be sorted correctly as a string, which may then work for Sqlite.

Comment: Yes, you should use Y-m-d formatting to ensure sorting is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Following the [documentation](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#datetimefield-datefield-and-timefield), I’d suggest

```
other = dt.date(1963, 1, 22)
Person.select().where(
    Person.birthday.year >= other.year
).where(
    Person.birthday.year > other.year
    | Person.birthday.month >= other.month
).where(
    Person.birthday.year > other.year
    | Person.birthday.month > other.month
    | Person.birthday.day > other.day
)
```

Yeah, it’s quite verbose...